# Trying to make an Excel usage graph user-proof

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts, resource-usage

I'm a stationary engineer in a large commercial facility. Recently we had a spike in our utility billing, and my boss wanted me to improve our tracking of usage so that we don't get surprised again.

We've got nightly meter readings going back roughly fifty years (no, I haven't dug into the really old ones!) but no one ever put them into a spreadsheet or other format to make daily tracking easier. I sat down and entered the most recent month's data into a template I created with the hope of replicating it month by month and having an ongoing track of usage. So far, so good.

The problem comes when some readings are missed. It's a big facility and the midnight man has a host of other things to do. So, if a water reading is missed, I show negative consumption of four hundred million gallons one day and a positive spike of four hundred million ten thousand gallons the next day. I can deal with the former by using the MAX(0, C12-C11) function, but I haven't found a good way to deal with the latter.

I can manually edit things like this, yes, but the goal is to turn it over to be used by some guys who don't all have a great degree of computer literacy. What I'd like to do, if possible, is to find a way to straight-line average over missing data points and reflect that in the graph by not showing the point markers. I can still deal with things such as meter replacements or rollovers by manual editing, but missing data is a routine enough problem that I'd like to be able to handle it automatically.

I should also mention that I'm largely unfamiliar with Excel; I've got much more time using LibreOffice Calc and Quattro Pro. I couldn't seem to figure out the requesters to do exactly what I want with the line graph. In addition to the daily usage, I also want to display high and low outside temperatures along with building occupancy on the same graph. Advice as to where to turn for a tutorial would be appreciated.

I wanted to post the spreadsheet as it stands now but I can't find a way to attach a file to this question...so some preliminary advice is welcome as well.

**Image of current spreadsheet:**
[image: Selection of Spreadsheet showing data table and pivot table]

Comment: Can you show us sample data and the associate chart?

Comment: I use very low tech for this (for years at customers).  Secure server folder for the base document. No one but me has access. User folder for a copy. If they change it, just replace it. Works like a charm.

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad I'm trying to, but I haven't found a way to attach an Excel file to my question. Suggestions?

Comment: See [Format Text as a Table](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/text_tables) for a web utility that will help you to create a nice data table you can paste into your question. Upload any image(s) to [Imgur](http://www.imgur.com) and you will get link(s) you can share. [Edit] your question to include the link(s) and someone with sufficient reputation will inline the image(s) for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Max test misses multiple error paths

---

**MAX** ignores the validity of values in each cell instead relying on a limited error path where the difference between the values is less than zero.

When you use 'MAX' to test if C12-C11 is > 0, the result is '0' **ALWAYS, AND ONLY IF** 'C12 NOT GREATER THAN C11' regardless of the values (positive, negative) of 'C12' and 'C11'.  Because of this narrow scope, it doesn't work for your second use case as well as others:

```
----------------------------
Tests using 'MAX(0,C12-C11)'
----------------------------
C11=160,C12=189  
   • MAX(0,19)        # 19  (Succeeds)

C11=189,C12=0  
   • MAX(0,-189)      #  0  (Succeeds)

C11=0,C12=0      
   • MAX(0,0)         #  0  (Succeeds)

C11=0,C12=189
   • MAX(0,189)       #  189 (Fails, '0' wanted) 

C11=(-189),C12=181
   • MAX(0,370)       #  370 (Fails, '0' wanted, see note 1) 

C11=("oops"),C12=181
   • MAX(0,#VALUE!)   #  #VALUE! (Fails, '0' wanted, see note 2)
```

**NOTES:**

1. Your test will fail to return '0' for real numbers that are <> 0 but outside of a reasonable range unless the difference is < 0.
2. Your current test will error with #VALUE! on a non-numeric entry such an accidental text entry in your data set.  This could be a text entry, a number that is stored as text "1849", or seemingly empty cell with hidden formatting such as a single quote (').   instead of nothing, you will generate errors when using it in a subtraction or any other calculations.

### Test validity of both values

---

If we assume from your use case that you only want to perform the calculation 'C12-C11' in cases where both values are numbers greater than zero, then the test would be **'AND(C11>0,C12>0)=true'** prior to your formula:

```
-----------------------------
Tests using 'AND(C11>0,C12>0'
-----------------------------

C11=160,C12=189  
   • AND(true,true)   # true

C11=189,C12=0  
   • AND(true,false)  # false

C11=0,C12=0      
   • AND(false,false) # false

C11=0,C12=189
   • AND(false,true)  # false

C11=(-189),C12=181
   • AND(false,true)  # false
```

**Issue with text values.**

Excel has idiosyncrasies when comparing different data types, they can vary depending on the formulae being used.  This allows text values to slip through and trigger the same error to which your MAX approach was exposed (note 2 above).

**Specific to this use case:**

```
    # In Excel, '[text] > [number]' is 'true'
      • oops > 1,000,000 is true
      • ' > 0 is also 'true' 

    C11=("oops"),C12=181  
       • AND(true*,true)   # true (*C11 should be false)

   #  I suggest 2 ways to resolve this below (IFERROR vs ISNUMBER).
```

### Adapt formula to include test

---

**Error Handling**
Because:

```
[number (or text)] - [text] = #VALUE! error
and
[text] - [number (or text)] = #VALUE! error
```

We can resolve that by including an ISNUMBER test of each of C11 and C12 to confirm they are numbers:

```
AND(ISNUMBER(C11),ISNUMBER(C12))
```

or we can alternatively skip the additional two tests and handle the error if triggered using the IFERROR function:

```
IFERROR([formula],[value_if_error])
```

The choice you make (and other approaches that are available) will depend on how you adapt the formula to your needs and what other calculations you are using.

Also, if C12 and C11 themselves refer to data elsewhere in the workbook you may choose to perform number checking / error checking earlier in the process.

```
-----------------------------------------
Formulae based on test 'AND(C11>0,C12>0)'*
-----------------------------------------   

* Includes IFERROR handling or ISNUMBER check

If both C11 and C12 must be positive numbers: 
   • =IFERROR(IF(AND(C11>0,C12>0),C12-C11,0),0)
       or 
   • =IF(AND(C11>0,ISNUMBER(C11),C12>0,ISNUMBER(C12)),C12-C11,0)
       or 
   • =IF(AND(ISNUMBER(C11),ISNUMBER(C12)),
         IF(AND(C11>0,C12>0,
            C12-C11,
            0),
         "custom error msg")  

added C12 must always be greater than C11:
   • =IFERROR(IF(AND(C11>0,C12>0,C12>C11),C12-C11,0),0)
       or 
   • =IF(AND(C11>0,ISNUMBER(C11),C12>0,ISNUMBER(C12)),C12>C11),C12-C11,0)

added C12 must always be at least 10% bigger than C11:
   • =IFERROR(IF(AND(C11>0,C12>0,C12>C11/.9),C12-C11,0),0)
       or 
   • =IF(AND(C11>0,ISNUMBER(C11),C12>0,ISNUMBER(C12),C12>C11/.9),C12-C11,0)

and so on...
```

Hope that helps :-)

---

.
.
.
.

### This may also be of interest

Error handling is sometimes intentionally triggered by people when they want to pass a value that needs (or is expected) to be a real number.

**Trigger Error if not Real Number**

**1/(1/[myValue])**  (Excludes '0' from Real Numbers)

```
# value=(Number<>0)
   • 1/(1/[myValue]) = [myValue]  

# value=0 (or equivalent)
   • 1/(1/[myValue]) = #DIV/0!   (error)
       
# value=Non-Number (e.g. text)
   • 1/(1/[myValue]) = #VALUE!    (error)
```

**[myValue]*1**  (Includes '0')

```
# value = (Number < > = 0)
   • [myValue] * 1 = [myValue]  
    
# value=Non-Number (e.g. text)
   • [myValue] * 1 = #VALUE!        (error)
```

These tests can be combine with IFERROR to pass a [myValue] or [alternateValue] and can be nested in other formulae:

```
=IFERROR(1/(1/[myValue]),[alternateValue]) 
=IFERROR([myValue]*1,[alternateValue])
```